# Why do I have a Debian grub boot loader with Debian listed as the default OS to boot showing on my Laptop when I never installed Debian?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, grub

I have an old Thinkpad T410, originally had Windows 7. Then I installed Linux Mint to dual boot. Later I made space and installed Ubuntu as my main operating system, but still have Mint and Windows 7 there. So far so good. Everything was as you'd expect, booting up would display the ubuntu bootloader with the ubuntu options top of the list.

Recently the bootloader changed although I have not done anything to change it. Now I get the following on boot

```
GNU Grub Version 2.02

*Debian GNU/Linux
 Advanced Options for Debian GNU/Linux
 ...
```

with the other boot options listed underneath and no mention of Ubuntu at all. letting it boot to the default "Debian GNU/Linux" option shows a Debian8 splash screen, then boots to ubuntu 18.

uname -a gives output as follows:

```
john@john-ThinkPad-T410:~$ uname -a
Linux john-ThinkPad-T410 5.3.0-45-generic #37~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 27 15:58:10 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am completely at a loss to explain this. I've never installed Debian on any machine.

Comment: The Linux Mint Debian Edition (LMDE) uses Debian Stable as the software source base rather than Ubuntu.  Do you have UEFI or BIOS boot? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: While @oldfred likely has the correct answer, also take a look at the grub.cfg file, just in case that is where that menu entry comes from. If so, you'll need to rewrite the relevant files (viz. /etc/default/grub & one or more under /etc/grub.d) then run grub-mkconfig. (If I've lost you with that terse explanation, there are many helpful pages on the web that explain in fuller detail what I just told you; you can find them if you Google any of those key words.)